# How to move Row to another sheet when a value in Col 11 = Yes with a Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have a summary in Sheet 2 ("Members") which is fed from a form in sheet 1 ("Reception"). Once the task has been updated and completed is set to Yes in sheet 1 and then save auto in sheet 2, i would like to run a script to move row from "Members" to "Archive" if value updated in Reception for completed is set to Yes. Actualy to make it work i put a button with a script in "members" and i must be place on cell with value Yes to move the row to "Archive"... I want it to be automated..

Can you help me?

Here's the Script i use:

```
// callFunctionB() cause i use onEdit(e) { callFunctionA(e);callFunctionB(e) }

function callFunctionB(e) {

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveRange();
  if(s.getName() == "Members" && r.getColumn() == 11 && r.getValue() == 'Yes') {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered looking at any addons, there are some available, eg: https://gsuite.google.com/u/0/marketplace/app/flow/909859924833

Answer (score 1):

```
function callB(e) {
  var s=e.range.getSheet();
  if(s.getName()=="Members" && e.range.columnStart==11 && e.value=='Yes') {
    e.source.getSheetByName("Archive").appendRow(s.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]);
    s.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, i tried it but : TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined. Do you know why?

Comment: You can't run the function without the onedit event object.  i.e. You can't run it from the script editor.

Comment: I start from a onEdit function like that: ```function onEdit(e) {
    callFunctionA(e)
  callFunctionB(e)
} ```  But it don't work too.